# jQuery: Need to add Class "active"

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my code,

Detail:
i have 2 divs, and when i click on (first link) so (first detail) open.
then i click on (second link) so (second detail) open.
and now i need that when i click on (first link) so add class `active` in first link,
and when i click on (second link) and now (first link) active class remove and added the active class (second link). and when i again click on (second link) then active class remove.

This is the code where i click. i need to add "Active" class in `<a>` Tag. through jQuery. how can i add in jquery?

[Codepen Fiddle](http://codepen.io/scriptscale/pen/KaEZgM)

```
<style>
   /* product-row */
   .product-row{ clear:both; padding:10px 0 20px 0;}
   .product-row .product-main{ width:225px; float:left; margin:0 60px 25px 0;}
   .product-row .product-main .product-img{ height:80px; text-align:center; margin:0 auto;}
   .product-row .product-main .product-title h2 a{ font-family:'Roboto Condensed'; font-size:20px; color:#343434; clear:both; display:block; text-align:center; line-height:42px; position:relative; text-transform:uppercase; margin:10px 0 0 0;}
   .product-row .product-main .product-title h2 a:hover{ background:url(../images/product-title-hover.png) bottom center no-repeat;}
   .product-row .product-detail{ clear:both; height:150px; background:#e2ddcf;}
   .det1, .det2, .det3, .det4, .det5, .det6, .det7, .det8{ display:none;}
   .product-row .product-detail .product-detail-row{ clear:both; padding:30px 0 0 30px;}
   .product-row .product-detail .product-detail-row .product-detail-main{ width:540px; float:left;}
   .product-row .product-detail .product-detail-row .product-detail-main ul{ margin:0; padding:0px; list-style:none;}
   .product-row .product-detail .product-detail-row .product-detail-main ul li{ font-family:'Tahoma'; font-size:14px; color:#686868; clear:both; padding:0 0 0 25px; background:url(../images/valores-text-bg.png) left 5px no-repeat; line-height:20px; margin:0 0 15px 0; height:25px;}
</style>
<div class="product-main">
                <div class="product-img"><a href="#"><img src="images/product-img-4.png" alt=""></a></div><!-- .product-img -->
                <div class="product-title"><h2><a href="#" id="prod1">FUSÕES E AQUISIÇÕES</a></h2></div><!-- .product-title -->
            </div><!-- .product-main -->
            <div class="product-main">
                <div class="product-img"><a href="#"><img src="images/product-img-3.png" alt=""></a></div><!-- .product-img -->
                <div class="product-title"><h2><a href="#" id="prod2">FUSÕES E AQUISIÇÕES</a></h2></div><!-- .product-title -->
            </div><!-- .product-main -->
            <div class="product-main">
                <div class="product-img"><a href="#"><img src="images/product-img-2.png" alt=""></a></div><!-- .product-img -->
                <div class="product-title"><h2><a href="#" id="prod3">FUSÕES E AQUISIÇÕES</a></h2></div><!-- .product-title -->
            </div><!-- .product-main -->
            <div class="product-main">
                <div class="product-img"><a href="#"><img src="images/product-img-5.png" alt=""></a></div><!-- .product-img -->
                <div class="product-title"><h2><a href="#" id="prod4">avaliação de empresas</a></h2></div><!-- .product-title -->
            </div><!-- .product-main -->
            <div class="product-detail det1 cf">
                <div class="product-detail-row cf">
                    <div class="product-detail-main">
                        <ul>
                            <li>1</li>
                            <li>Identificação e abordagem de metas de aquisição adequadas em nível nacional e internacional;</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- .product-detail-main -->
                    <div class="product-detail-main">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Prospecção de ofertas que melhor se adaptem aos objetivos estratégicos da<br> empresa;</li>
                            <li>Assessoria no desenvolvimento de um plano personalizado e estratégico de <br>negócios.</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- .product-detail-main -->
                </div><!-- .product-detail-row -->
            </div><!-- .product-detail -->
            <div class="product-detail det2 cf">
                <div class="product-detail-row cf">
                    <div class="product-detail-main">
                        <ul>
                            <li>2</li>
                            <li>Identificação e abordagem de metas de aquisição adequadas em nível nacional e internacional;</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- .product-detail-main -->
                    <div class="product-detail-main">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Prospecção de ofertas que melhor se adaptem aos objetivos estratégicos da<br> empresa;</li>
                            <li>Assessoria no desenvolvimento de um plano personalizado e estratégico de <br>negócios.</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- .product-detail-main -->
                </div><!-- .product-detail-row -->
            </div><!-- .product-detail -->
            <div class="product-detail det3 cf">
                <div class="product-detail-row cf">
                    <div class="product-detail-main">
                        <ul>
                            <li>3</li>
                            <li>Identificação e abordagem de metas de aquisição adequadas em nível nacional e internacional;</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- .product-detail-main -->
                    <div class="product-detail-main">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Prospecção de ofertas que melhor se adaptem aos objetivos estratégicos da<br> empresa;</li>
                            <li>Assessoria no desenvolvimento de um plano personalizado e estratégico de <br>negócios.</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- .product-detail-main -->
                </div><!-- .product-detail-row -->
            </div><!-- .product-detail -->
            <div class="product-detail det4 cf">
                <div class="product-detail-row cf">
                    <div class="product-detail-main">
                        <ul>
                            <li>4</li>
                            <li>Identificação e abordagem de metas de aquisição adequadas em nível nacional e internacional;</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- .product-detail-main -->
                    <div class="product-detail-main">
                        <ul>
                            <li>Prospecção de ofertas que melhor se adaptem aos objetivos estratégicos da<br> empresa;</li>
                            <li>Assessoria no desenvolvimento de um plano personalizado e estratégico de <br>negócios.</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- .product-detail-main -->
                </div><!-- .product-detail-row -->
            </div><!-- .product-detail -->
<script>
$(function () {

   jQuery('a[id^="prod"]').on('click', function (e) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').slice(-1);
    var previs = $('div.product-detail:visible');
    $('div.product-detail').hide();
    if (previs.is($('.det' + id))) {
        $('.det' + id).hide()
    }
    else
    {
        $('.det' + id).show();
    }

    //if (detailedDiv.is(':visible')) detailedDiv.hide();
    //else detailedDiv.show();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    e.preventDefault()
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _add "Active"_? A class, you mean?

Comment: Do you mean to add a div with the class 'active' to be appended inside the a tag? provide detail (or example) of how code should look after clicking button.

Comment: i need like this ( active on a tag) `<a href="#" id="prod1" class"active">FUSÕES E AQUISIÇÕES</a>`

Comment: Please put all relevant code in the question itself. Questions should be self contained and we shouldn't have to go off-site to review your issue. Demos are great...but only as support for what actually exists in the question itself. See [mcve]

Comment: `$("#prod1").on("click", function() { if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) $(this).addClass("active") });` - something like this?

Comment: @scriptscale do you want to put the class on the link itself ot on the parent div???

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir yes i need to add active class when i click on link.

Comment: @scriptscale I updated my answer now it should work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instructions are a bit hard to follow but I think this may be what you're after...

```
var $prodLinks = $('a[id^="prod"]');
$prodLinks.on("click", function() {   //On the click of any link

    $prodLinks.not(this).removeClass("active");   //Remove active from all other links
    $(this).toggleClass("active");   //Toggle the active class for the clicked link

});
```

Comment: where can i put this?

Comment: Inside your `$(function () { ... });` section at the bottom of your snippet.

Comment: Please see this example: https://jsfiddle.net/w8cyfdrf/ - It seems to be doing exactly what you've asked for, unless of course I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: here is allow share skype id ? i wanna show you my screen

Comment: Replace this line: `$(this).toggleClass('active');` in your current code, with my entire supplied code above. And no, I will not be sharing my Skype ID, I believe I've provided all the tools necessary to provide you with a sufficient answer. If it doesn't work, there must be something else interfering.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:
It's kind of ugly, but maybe could help.

```
$('.product-main .product-title a').on('click', function(){

    $(this).addClass('active');        
    $(this).parents('.product-main')                    
            .siblings()
            .children('.product-title').children('h2').children('a')
            .removeClass('active');

});
```

Comment: You're, it's not dynamic, but based on the question, it looks like that what he needs to.

Comment: @MohammadIbrahim this code working but when i click again a link for hide related div so class active not remove.. but other worked. just 1 bug

Comment: Okay, scriptscale, you can change the addClass() to toggleClass() and it will just work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `jQuery` toggle function, to toggle the class on the link.

`jQuery('a[id^="prod"]').on('click', function (e) {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
    ...`

Comment: your code adding class active but when i click another link so its not remove and also not adding second link. because i used 6 links it works like collapse

Answer (score -1):

Just add an event onClick on your element and execute this code into :

```
$('#prod1').addClass('Active');
```